# Angular - Get text from button to show different content in modal

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm currently learning Angular and Typescript, I don't know much yet

I have a table which shows data from an array of objects with ngFor

```
<tbody *ngFor="let book of tableBooklist">
  <tr>
    <td>{{book.title}}</td>
    <td>
      <button (click)="toggleModal()" class="btn btn-link">{{book.author.nameAut + ' ' + book.author.surnameAut}}</button>
    </td>
    <td>{{book.publicationYear}}</td>
    <td>{{book.publisher}}</td>
    <td>{{book.genre}}</td>
    <td>{{book.numberOfCopies}}</td>
    <td>{{book.firstPublication}}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

The button triggers a modal component. I need to read the name of the button I clicked in order to show different content on my modal.
For example, I click on the button with the name "Lev Tolstoj" and the modal shows the details from the author (that I have in my array).

I don't know how to get the content from the button, since I print it with ngFor.

Comment: Why do you have the ngFor on `tbody`? Shouldn't it be on `tr`?

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm I need to print all properties of all objects in my array, so in thead I have the titles of the columns and in every row I need to print for every column a different property of one of my objects. Then another row for another object, and so on. I only got it to work this way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the book object as parameter.

```
 <td>
  <button (click)="toggleModal(book)" class="btn btn-link">{{book.author.nameAut + ' ' + book.author.surnameAut}}</button>
</td>
```

You can access the book object and pass it to your modal

```
public toggleModal(book: Book){
     //code to pass book (book.author) to your modal
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand how to do it, I've been learning for just a few weeks. toggleModal() passes with output a boolean to the parent in order to show the modal component (the child). How do I pass the book to the parent, create a variable there, assign it the book and pass it to my modal component?

Comment: Instead of boolean you have to pass entire book object as output.